# Kafka stream : Is there a way to ignore specific offsets in a topic partition while writing to another topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

Background: i used wrong avro schema registry while producing to prod topic and as a result the kafka connect went down because of the messages with wrong schema id.So as a recovery plan we wanted to copy the messages in the prod topic to a test topic and then write the good messages to the hdfs.But we are facing issues with certain offsets that have wrong schema id while reading from prod topic.Is there a way to ignore such offsets while writing to another topic.

```
 Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" 
 org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to deserialize value 
 for record. topic=xxxx, partition=9, offset=1259032
  Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error 
  retrieving Avro schema for id 600
  Caused by: 

  io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: 
   Schema not found io.confluent.rest.exceptions.RestNotFoundException: Schema not found
  io.confluent.rest.exceptions.RestNotFoundException: Schema not found
```

{code}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the deserialization exception handler to skip over those record as describe in the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#handling-corrupted-records-and-deserialization-errors-poison-pill-records

Ie, you set `LogAndContinueExceptionHandler` in the config via parameter `default.deserialization.exception.handler`.